# Как выгрузить ссылки на чаты (список) из телеграм где ты уже есть?

Tags: telegram, ссылки

Нужен бот или способ как выгрузить списком все чаты ссылками в Exell например.
В экспорте тг есть только выгрузка сообщений в чатах, не то.